# Specifying destination folder for WinSCP script executed with Task Scheduler

Tags: ftp, scheduled-tasks, winscp, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to do an automated backup from a FTP server to a local external hard drive. The following script works with WinSCP when run manually from the external hard drive destination folder:

```
E:\Backups\FTP>"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /ini=nul /script="E:\Backups\ftptpp.txt"
```

I have little experience with scheduling tasks in Windows and am using Windows 8.1. Following the WinSCP guide, I have written this so far:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /log="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul /script="E:\Backups\ftptpp.txt"
```

However, in the original script I ran manually, I ran it from the destination folder. How do I specify in the task scheduler where the destination folder is located (E:\Backups\FTP)?

For reference, the ftptpp.txt script looks like this:

```
# Connect
  open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.org/
# Change remote directory
  cd /
# Download file to the local directory
  synchronize local
# Disconnect
  close
# Exit WinSCP
  exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying an *"Action"* for your scheduled task, there's a field called *"Start in"*.  That corresponds to the directory you "ran" your script manually from, i.e. the *"destination folder"* `E:\Backups\FTP`.

---

Though I'd personally suggest you to specify the destination folder directly in WinSCP script:

```
synchronize local E:\Backups\FTP /
```

or

```
cd /
lcd E:\Backups\FTP
synchronize local
```

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize

---

Side note: Unless you run the task with Administrator privileges (what you should not!), you cannot log to "Program Files" folder, so this will not work:

```
/log="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.log"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I'll use the first suggestion on the next scheduled run and I'm sure that will do the trick.